# Pause and/or resume audio using Python on Linux

Tags: python, linux, audio, resume, pause

thank you for your attention! I want to pause and/or resume audio which is being played at the background using python, found this way, which uses `pynput`:

```py
from pynput.keyboard import Controller, Key

c = Controller()
c.press(Key.media_play_pause)
```

But audio is still playing. Seems there are no errors, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try using [*playerctl*](https://github.com/altdesktop/playerctl), a command line tool that you could use with

```
subprocess.call(("playerctl", "play-pause"))
```

However, playerctl might not come preinstalled on your system, so you might have to

- `sudo apt install playerctl`,
- `pacman -Syu playerctl`,
- `sudo dnf install playerctl` or
- `sudo zypper install playerctl`

(depending on your distro)

This would not require `pynput`, but `subprocess` (`import subprocess`). If you don't care about style and security you could of course also use `os.system("playerctl play-pause")`

Comment: It pauses, and plays. Thank you! I often use telegram while working, that's why i needed to control the music via bot, so i wouldn't switch windows, turn on/off and go back! Thank you!